# What's the ideal way of combining two Object Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, spring

Class A:

```
public class A{
   private String Id;
   private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Product{
   private String prodId;
   private String color;
   private String size;
}
```

Example:

```
A = { "Id": 1 , products: [{"prodId":"Prod1", "color":"Red", "size":"L"},
    {"prodId":"Prod2", "color":"Green", "size":"L"}] }
```

Class B:

```
public class B{
   private String Id;
   private List<ProductAvail> productAvail = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ProductAvail{
   private String prodId;
   private String availability;
   private String region;
}
```

Example:

```
B =  { "Id": 1 , productAvail: [{"prodId":"Prod1", "availability":"Y", "region":"AA"},
     {"prodId":"Prod2", "availability":"N", "region":"BB"}] }
```

I want to combine them into one like

```
public class C{
   private String Id;
   private List<Catalog> catalog = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Catalog{
   private String prodId;
   private String color;
   private String size;
   private String availability;
   private String region;
}

C =  { "Id": 1 , catalog: [{"prodId":"Prod1", "color":"Red", "size":"L", "availability":"Y", "region":"AA"},
 {"prodId":"Prod2", "color":"Green", "size":"L", "availability":"N", "region":"BB"}] }
```

What's the ideal way to do this in Java without using two for loops?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've parsed it, want to combine into one, Please see example above

Answer (score -1):

Given:

```
String aJson = "{ \"id\": 1 ,\"products\": [{\"prodId\":\"Prod1\", \"color\":\"Red\", \"size\":\"L\"}, {\"prodId\":\"Prod2\", \"color\":\"Green\", \"size\":\"L\"}] }";
String bJson = "{ \"id\": 1 ,\"productAvail\": [{\"prodId\":\"Prod1\", \"availability\":\"Y\", \"region\":\"AA\"}, {\"prodId\":\"Prod2\", \"availability\":\"N\", \"region\":\"BB\"}] }";
```

You can do:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

A a = objectMapper.readValue(aJson, A.class);
B b = objectMapper.readValue(bJson, B.class);

Map<String, ProductAvail> idToProductAvail = b.getProductAvail().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ProductAvail::getProdId, Function.identity()));

List<Catalog> catalogs = a.getProducts().stream()
        .map(p -> {
            ProductAvail pa = idToProductAvail.get(p.getProdId());
            return new Catalog(pa.getProdId(), p.getColor(), p.getSize(),
    pa.getAvailability(), pa.getRegion());
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

C c = new C(a.getId(), catalogs);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(c));
```

Output:

```
{"id":"1","catalog":[{"prodId":"Prod1","color":"Red","size":"L","availability":"Y","region":"AA"},{"prodId":"Prod2","color":"Green","size":"L","availability":"N","region":"BB"}]}
```

Comment: The inclusion of JSON in this question seems incidental to me; the author asked for fast runs over two lists of objects in java, not interleaving the source data at read time with Jackson.

Comment: @RG-Rawlings Since the author provided JSONs, I figured it would be better to cover both cases and provide a complete detailed solution. I don't see where I did - "interleaving the source data at read time". I parsed the objects.

Comment: The question title and the author's comment say they want to work with A and B, not the data prior to that. Your solution is real, but their question smells of homework. :p

Comment: @RG-Rawlings In that case, you can just skip this part, and read from "Map<..".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to do this action in Java, *after* parsing your source data, you have two choices.

1. Guarantee that your source data is ordered by prodId for both lists, and that every Product has a corresponding ProductAvail. You can then simply assume that the index of the first has a valid entry at the same index in the second and traverse them both with a single loop.
2. Change your source data and class members such that you have Maps instead of Lists as output, using prodId as the key for each entry. You can then iterate the keys from the map of Products and use them to access both the Product and ProductAvail maps in a single loop.

-

If you *can't* make the guarantees from (1) or the changes from (2), you're stuck with your worst case of `foreach product { foreach productavail { ... } }` because you have to *discover* the correct ProductAvail for each Product.

You could take steps mitigate the impact by nulling discovered inner list members and skipping nulls, or by using parallelStream to throw the inner loop for each outer iteration at a different thread, but no action at this point avoids needing some riff on `loop{loop{}}` - as a best case.